# Do C variables saturate or wrap around?

Tags: c, variables

If I keep incrementing a `C` variable, does it saturate or wrap around?

Comment: Quick answer: it depends on the data type of the variable. Integer types wrap around, floating-point ones saturate.

Comment: Do you mean, as specified by standard, or as what happens in practice with all PC compilers?

Comment: If you are facing (potentially) this problem you should have a rethink of the algorithm.

Comment: @hyde: I meant it happens in practice. I dare not tell it is defined by standard, I saw a huge discussion somewhere on SO which didn't come to a definite conclusion

Comment: You should not push the envelop. The Victorians had the best idea - build things with plenty of tolerance and it will last longer.

Comment: @EdHeal It's not really a problem, it's just that if it saturates I can make the algorithm much simpler.

Comment: @Milad "SSE"/"MMX" instructions generally have saturating versions of integer operations, if it is really important (such as for performance-critical operation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For signed integer types, it's **undefined** as to what happens.

For unsigned integer types, it will wrap around (i.e. back to 0).

Comment: TIL signed integers in `C` do not form a group under addition. WTH?

Comment: @JanDvorak Behavior of signed integers on overflow is undefined, because C as language/standard supports different negative number binary representations, and as such it must leave signed integer overflow undefined.

Comment: @Jan: for example, what do you define `INT_MAX+1` to be in a sign-magnitude representation? If it's `INT_MIN+1` then integers aren't a group because `INT_MIN+1-1` can't be both `INT_MIN` *and* `INT_MAX`. If you make it `INT_MIN` then an odd number plus an odd number results in an odd number. It's an additive group but still not a ring.

Comment: @SteveJessop it is still a group if you define `INT_MAX == INT_MIN` and `0 == -0`

Comment: @Jan: I don't think users would be very happy with `INT_MAX` evaluating equal to `INT_MIN` either, that's even more confusing than overflow being UB. `0 == negative zero` is fine (indeed, required for implementations that support a negative zero).

Comment: @SteveJessop what if you forbid `-INT_MAX`? :-)

Comment: @Jan: then you've invented another obscure representation for signed types :-) But IIRC the C standard forbids it, because it explicitly lists the three allowed representations. If your representation had been implemented in hardware in the 80s, maybe standard C would allow that too.

Comment: @SteveJessop I'll guess: two's complement, ones' complement and sign-magnitude?

Comment: Making signed integer overflow undefined also enables certain loop optimizations that would not otherwise be possible: for instance, the compiler is allowed to assume `for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++)` terminates regardless of the value of `k` (if signed integer overflow wraps and `k == INT_MAX`, this is an infinite loop)

Comment: The kind of thing that catches people out is that if `i` is signed then the compiler is permitted to assume `if (i + 1 < i)` is always false, and eliminate the clause that follows it as dead code. Similarly it can simplify other expressions by ruling out cases that cause overflow. If `i` were unsigned (and of a type at least as wide as `int`) then it would have to actually do a test and execute the code in the case where wraparound occurs. I don't think these optimizations motivated the decision to make overflow UB, but because it is UB the optimizations are available.